# Does reinterpret_cast guarantee not to change the source pointer's address?

Tags: c++, c, casting, type-conversion, standards

```
auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<AnyType*>(p_any_other_type);
auto p2 = (AnyType*)(p_any_other_type);

void* p3 = (void*)p_any_other_type;
void* p4 = (void*)p2;
```

Does the C++ standard guarantee `p1` is always equal to `p2`?

Does the C standard guarantee `p3` is always equal to `p4`?

Does the C standard guarantee `p3` is always equal to `p_any_other_type`?

Comment: Do you mean 'reinterpret'?

Comment: Take a look at 5.2.10 (expr.reinterpret.cast) of the standard.

Comment: 1) no and 2) no. The first cast is implementation-defined, and the second cast can change the pointer value when two types are related by inheritance and implementation-defined in other cases.

Comment: @n.m. 2) is asking about the C standard.  There is no inheritance.  Are C pointer casts implementation-defined?

Comment: @DrewDormann where p2 in 2) comes from?

Comment: @n.m. I was going to say the `p2` line could also be C, but no - not with that use of `auto`.  A typo from OP, perhaps?

Comment: Correction, the C standard can guarantee nothing about p3 and p4 because they are unrelated because p2 and p_any_other_type are unrelated because C can guarantee nothing about C++.

Comment: If this is about C why does it have the C++ tag?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, reinterpret_cast is C++-specific

Comment: So maybe he is asking about C++.  In which case the question needs to be edited.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, both C and C++ are considered in this question.

Answer (score 2):

p1 != p2.  (AnyType *)(p) is static_cast<AnyType *>(p).  static_cast<X*>(y) can be different than reinterpret_cast<X*>(y) in cases of multiple inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AnyType { int x; };
class SomeType { int y; };
class OtherType : public SomeType, public AnyType {};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    OtherType o;
    OtherType *p_any_other_type = &o;

    auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<AnyType *>(p_any_other_type);
    auto p2 = (AnyType *)(p_any_other_type);

    void *p3 = (void *) p_any_other_type;
    void *p4 = (void *) p2;

    cout << p1 << endl << p2 << endl << p3 << endl << p4 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`g++ -Wno-c++11-extensions -o x x.cc` warns:

```
x.cc:12:15: warning: 'reinterpret_cast' from class 'OtherType *' to its base at
      non-zero offset 'AnyType *' behaves differently from 'static_cast'
      [-Wreinterpret-base-class]
    auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<AnyType *>(p_any_other_type);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
x.cc:12:15: note: use 'static_cast' to adjust the pointer correctly while upcasting
    auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<AnyType *>(p_any_other_type);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              static_cast
1 warning generated.
```

run:

```
0x7fff5e4c38f8
0x7fff5e4c38fc
0x7fff5e4c38f8
0x7fff5e4c38fc
```

Since p2 != p1, p3 != p4.

Comment: _"Since p2 != p1..."_ `p3` and `p4` have no relation to `p1` and C++ casts.  It was a C question.  (I had to review the question phrasing too)